# The npm command is giving a syntax error: unexpected token (mac)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I got this msg recently when I tried to use npm

```
Update available 5.3.0 → 7.11.1    │
   │      Run npm i -g npm to update
```

And so I went ahead and tried to update it and eversince have been getting this error
when I try to use the npm command

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:300
      ...this.defaults,
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:9:16)
```

Any help to fix this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would try updating your node version to LTS ([14.16.1](https://nodejs.org/en/)). Spread isn't supported if your node version is below 8.3 ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)). Can you share what you get when you run `node -v`?

Comment: Hi JBallin, my node version is v8.2.1

Comment: Thanks very much... upgrading node fixed the issue... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing that `node` doesn't understand the `...` [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

You should upgrade `node` to a version that has [full support for spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#browser_compatibility) (8.3+).

If possible, you should use the LTS (long-term support) version of `node` (currently [14.16.1](https://nodejs.org)).